# How to automatically update cache with a mutation that responses partial error

Tags: javascript, react-apollo

How to make **React Apollo** automatically updates the cache with the data from response of a mutation that has partial errors?

In the **Query**, I can pass the option `errorPolicy: 'all'` to make it work. However, both "all" and "ignore" policy does not help in the mutation, the cache isn't updated.

Version:

```
apollo-client: 2.6.4
react-apollo: 3.1.1
```

This is the first query to get set info:

```
fragment PurchasedCount on PurchasedCount {
  id
  purchased
}

query getSet {
  id
  limit
  purchasedCount { ...PurchasedCount }
}
```

After that, I use a mutation to purchase the set:

```
fragment Purchase on Purchase {
  createdAt
}

mutation purchase {
  purchase {
    purchase { ...Purchase }
    purchasedCount { ...PurchasedCount }
  }
}
```

Given someone else has purchased the set to the limit, the response will return limit exceeded error, together with the current purchased count value:

```
{
  data: {
    purchase: {
      purchasedCount: { id: 3, purchased: 10 },
      purchase: null
    }
  },
  errors: [{
    message: "limit_exceeded"
    ...
  }]
}
```

I expected the cache value for `purchased` will be updated automatically to `10`. However it only be updated if there is no error in the responses. I have to manually `writeFragment` in this case.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use update in mutation  what the data want to update  todos  is to read the data that found in cache with specific Query the need to write what you want in the cache by writeQuery the need to update the data look to simple example

```
const GET_TODOS = gql`
  query GetTodos {
    todos
  }
```

`;

```
const ADD_TODO= gql`
  mutation ADD_TODO($id: String!, $type: String!) {
    addTodo(id: $id, type: $type) {
      id
      type
    }
  }
`;

const [addTodo] = useMutation(
    ADD_TODO,
    {

 update(cache, { data: { addTodo } }) {
        const { todos } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_TODOS });
        cache.writeQuery({
          query: GET_TODOS,
          data: { todos: todos.concat([addTodo]) },
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to automatically update the cache. Since my object has id, it's suppose to be able to update the object cache with the default cache key when I use `fetchPolicy: all`, similar to `Query`.

FYI, `update` callback won't be called when there is an error as well.